# C++ SSE commands invert register values

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd

I have a array containing some int values (those at [position%2=0] are negative and those at  [position%2=1] are positive).

I want to load those values at a 4 step from the array to the register but I want them inverted (positive converted to negative and vice versa)

```
__m128i v1;
for (int k = 0; k < limit; k += 4) {
        v1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) & myArray[position + k]);
}
```

The above SSE code loads the values into register as is: Is there a command to take v1 and inverse it? Can it be done in one step / command? Is it even possible to load the values directly inverted from the original array?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want -1 to be 1 and 2 to be -2 then it's called "negation". Inversion is the bitwise not, i.e. invert all bits in the value, so -1 will become 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your integer elements are 32 bits then you can just subtract from 0, e.g.

```
v1 = _mm_load_si128(...);                   // load data
v1 = _mm_sub_epi32(_mm_set1_epi32(0), v1);  // negate all elements
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be:

```
__m128i v1 = _mm_xor_si128(
    _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&myArray[position + k]), 
    _mm_cmpeq_epi8(v1, v1)
);
```

Bascially we are doing this: `x ^ -1` assuming we are using a machine with twos complement so -1 is a sequence of all ones ...

note the following, where `~` means inversion and `^` means exclusive or.

```
~0 == 1 == (0 ^ 1)
~1 == 0 == (1 ^ 1)
```

`_mm_cmpeq_epi8(a, a)` will set all 1s while you could use `_mm_set1_epi32(-1)`, it may actually be slower since it may generate a memory access, I'd recommend profiling if performance is an issue ...